Depth-First Search for Optimal Route Not Returning Expected Results in C#
I'm working on a program to find an optimal travel route starting and ending at the same city. The goal is to find the best route with the best goodness rating of the visited cities. My data is read correctly from an Excel file, but the algorithm doesn't seem to return any results. Here's the relevant parts of my code:
static RouteResult FindOptimalRoute(string startCity, Dictionary<string, double> goodnessRatings, List<TravelData> travelData)
{
    var optimalRoute = new List<string>();
    double optimalGoodness = 0;

    void DFS(string currentCity, HashSet<string> visited, List<string> route, double currentGoodness)
    {
        if (route.Count > 1 && currentCity == startCity)
        {
            if (currentGoodness > optimalGoodness)
            {
                optimalGoodness = currentGoodness;
                optimalRoute = new List<string>(route);
            }
            return;
        }

        foreach (var travel in travelData)
        {
            if (travel.FromCity == currentCity && !visited.Contains(travel.ToCity))
            {
                visited.Add(travel.ToCity);
                route.Add(travel.ToCity);

                double cityGoodness = goodnessRatings.TryGetValue(travel.ToCity, out double value) ? value : 0;
                DFS(travel.ToCity, visited, route, currentGoodness + cityGoodness);

                visited.Remove(travel.ToCity);
                route.RemoveAt(route.Count - 1);
            }
        }
    }

    var initialVisited = new HashSet<string> { startCity };
    var initialRoute = new List<string> { startCity };

    double startCityGoodness = goodnessRatings.TryGetValue(startCity, out double startValue) ? startValue : 0;
    DFS(startCity, initialVisited, initialRoute, startCityGoodness);

    return new RouteResult(optimalRoute, optimalGoodness);
}

internal class RouteResult
{
    public List<string> Route { get; }
    public double TotalGoodness { get; }

    public RouteResult(List<string> route, double totalGoodness)
    {
        Route = route;
        TotalGoodness = totalGoodness;
    }
}

internal class TravelData
{
    public string FromCity { get; }
    public string ToCity { get; }
    public int Time { get; }

    public TravelData(string fromCity, string toCity, int time)
    {
        FromCity = fromCity;
        ToCity = toCity;
        Time = time;
    }
}

Verified that the Excel data is correctly parsed.
Used the debugger to trace the data flow. Given there are approximately 2000 cities, I couldn't verify every step, but from what I observed, the data seems to be processed correctly.

You're backtracking. Right? In that case, shouldn't you DFS for every city?

Reduce the size to 5 cities, or something similar, and try to reproduce the situation where   the result is not as you expected it.
